# Cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a form and fetch values in checkbox using HTML helper, from the database. But the **Runtime error** pops up stating:

> cannot Convert **List<> to IEnumerable<>**
>   **Error:
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

I tried to explicitly convert the `List<>` type to `IEnumerable<>` but the error stays as an `InternalError`.

```
MembershipTypes = (IEnumerable<MembershipTypes>) membershipTypes
```

Did converted the `IEnumerable<> MembershipTypes` to `List<>` but no luck

```
//The Controller Class
var membershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList();
var viewModel = new NewCustomerviewModel { MembershipTypes = membershipTypes };
return View(viewModel);

//The NewCustomerViewModel Class (a ModelView Class)
public IEnumerable<MembershipTypes> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
public Customers Customers{ get; set; }

// THE VIEW CLASS
@Html.CheckBoxFor(
    m => m.Customers.MembershipTypes,
    new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes,"Id", "Name"),
    "Select Membership Type",
    new { @class = "form-control" }
);
```

Comment: Can you post the _actual_ error message which includes the *generic type arguments* of `List<>` and `IEnumerable<>`? It’s likely that the types do not match here.

Comment: I'd assume you're trying to assign `List<DAO>` to `IEnumerable<DTO>`, but we need a proper error message exactly as it appears, like poke suggests. I don't get why people remove crucial information from exceptions.

Comment: Is the missing 'h' just a typo, in `public IEnumerable<MembersipTypes>` - did you mean `MembershipTypes`? As @poke wrote above, the error is probably caused because of mismatched types.

Comment: Hi guys... that Error Message is gone as @eja pointed out my typo error... Thank you
But I have a new error at:
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customers.MembershipTypes,.............)
Stating:
1. Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type and
2. 'Vidly.Models.MembershipTypes' to 'bool'

Comment: @WesMes Would you add the definition of the `NewCustomerviewModel` class?

Comment: Change thi var membershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.ToList(); to var membershipTypes = _context.MembershipTypes.AsEnumerable();